# Python executables without python installed on target PC

Tags: python, kivy, py2exe

I have heard, that Python programs can be "converted" into executables files. My question are:

1. Will that executable work on PC, where is not installed python?
2. Will that executable work on PC, where are not installed all libraries, which I installed manually with pip for "development"?
3. If answer to previous questions is YES, then - will running my executable firstly install python and used library?

Thanks!

Comment: See Ishwar's answer on how to do it, I just want do add that due to the fact that all the libraries and required interpreter are packed into the executable, even the simplest python scripts can result in pretty large executable files.

Comment: The meaning of having an executable is that it is already compile to machine code. So, no, if you have an .exe (no matter which language you used) there will be no need to install any libraries and especially the python interpreter. The only reason you would wouldn't be able to run your program is if it includes any platform specific DLLs that are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will that executable work on PC, where is not installed python?

```
Yes
```

Will that executable work on PC, where are not installed all libraries, which I installed manually with pip for "development"?

```
Yes
```

If answer to previous questions is YES, then - will running my executable firstly install python and used library?

```
No need to install python just run newly created .exe on windows machine by copy paste on it.
```

Yes you can do it using pyinstaller.
On your machine do run

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'
```

This will create ‘dist’ folder above. Here you will get your ‘.exe’ file.

```
Ref:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/
```